# How can remove PostgreSQL with all configuration and intial data from Manjaro?

Tags: postgresql, manjaro

I want to remove PostgreSQL with all initial data and configuration. Because, **postgres** user has default password and I do not know what is it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The following command worked for me
`sudo pacman -Rcns postgresql`

Comment: Avoid the use of sudo while referencing the commands inside the postgres

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).